# Can't parse File and Handler in SAXParser

Tags: java, xml, sax, saxparser

I'm passing in an XML file and a handler to the SAXParser but I'm getting this error:
[image: Cannot resolve method 'parse(java.io.File, jdk.internal.org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler)']

The attributes for the parse method are defined as (File, DefaultHandler) which match exactly, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Here is the full method:

```
public String readXML (File readFile) throws Exception {
    SAXParserFactory saxFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser saxParser = saxFactory.newSAXParser();
    final String outputString = "";
    DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {
        boolean bArtist    = false;
        boolean bAlbumName = false;
        boolean bYear      = false;
        boolean bGenre     = false;

        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attr)
                throws SAXException {
            if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("ARTIST"))    { bArtist = true; }
            if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("ALBUMNAME")) { bAlbumName = true; }
            if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("YEAR"))      { bYear = true; }
            if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("GENRE"))     { bGenre = true; }
        }
        public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
            if (bArtist) {
                outputString.concat("Artist: " + new String(ch,start,length) + "\n");
            }
            if(bAlbumName) {
                outputString.concat("Album: " + new String(ch,start,length) + "\n");
            }
            if(bYear) {
                outputString.concat("Year: " + new String(ch,start,length) + "\n");
            }
            if(bGenre) {
                outputString.concat("Genre: " + new String(ch,start,length) + "\n");
            }
            outputString.concat("\n");
        }
    };

    saxParser.parse(readFile,handler);
    return outputString;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler`
not `jdk.internal...`

so

```
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
```

You should probably also define the class that extends the DefaultHandler not just inline it.

Comment: Why would it be better to define it rather than inline it?

Comment: just a better practise. As the inner class it holds the reference to the containing class, potential memory leak.

Comment: How would I change it to be a class rather than inline? Would it just be a case of creating a new subclass starting with something like `private Handler () extends DefaultHandler { ... }` ?

Comment: yes, but `static class Handler extends DefaultHandler { ... }`if it is inside of your outer class code (otherwise it still has the reference to the class), or of course a totatly separate class. Also make sure that you add @Overrride on top of the methods, it will help you detect potential import problems, for excample there are many Attributes classes and if you import the wrong one the method will not be called but the parent one instead.